# (App) has stopped working

Tags: 5.1-lollipop, crashes

I know there are already several posts about it ([this one for example](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/23842/unfortunately-launcher-has-stopped-error-after-4-0-4-ota-upgrade)), but all the solution I found on this one, or one the Internet in general, didn't fix my problem.

My phone is a [Wiko Fever](http://world.wikomobile.com/m889-fever), with the Android OS 5.1 (Lollipop) :

While launching, or performing a specific action in several apps, I have the error log :

> Unfortunately, (process) has stopped working.

*I guess it's something like that, since my OS is not in english*

---

As I said, I have this problem **only** on several applications :

- The default SMS/MMS application (when **opening a conversation**)
  I can still receive messages, but can't open them in a conversation.
- [Gmail](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.gm&hl=en_GB) (when **opening an e-mail**)
- [Steam](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.valvesoftware.android.steam.community&hl=fr) (at **launch**)
- [Stack Exchange](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.stackexchange.marvin&hl=fr) (when **redirecting to a post**, not in the menus)

I have tried almost everything said on the Internet :

1. Clearing App Cache
   *I rebooted my phone afterwards*
2. Removing App Data
   *I rebooted my phone afterwards*
3. Uninstalling and Reinstalling the app
4. Rebooting the phone in `Recovery Mode` then cleared phone cache

---

I fear the last resort which is the **factory reset**.

Do you have any idea what could be the cause, but mostly, **the solution** of this problem ? Thank you in advance !

Comment: Is your phone running stock or custom Lollipop? Did you apply some sort of theme?

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman It's a stock Lollipop. I bought the phone about a month ago, and I just got an upgrade to 5.1 since. But I didn't change anything else. No theme either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found the cause of the problem :
It was due to the [Android System Webview](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-Android-system-WebView-app-and-how-can-I-use-it) which was bugging and then couldn't display web UI on several applications.

I just had an update of it and now everything works fine !

One of the update's patch notes (*translated from French, it may not be perfect*) :

> Resolved crashes in applications using WebView in an application context